# Objects moving together after creation

Tags: objects, selection-tools, parent

I'm **VERY** new to blender so if I'm making a very obvious mistake, please go easy on me. Pretty much, whenever I create a new object and move it, it moves with another object I previously created. I tried pressing clear parent but it did nothing. Just to clarify, this is when I create a NEW object and I have tried creating it without having a previous object selected in scene collector but to no avail. Any help would mean a lot!

Comment: Make sure you don't have Proportional Editing enabled (O key)

Comment: Yeah, that seems to have fixed it, Thanks!